# How to parse JSON with fromJSON on a dataframe column?

Tags: json, r, rjson

I have the following data.frame with one column called "json" and two rows of JSON data:

```
df <- data.frame(json = c('{"client":"ABC Company","totalUSD":7110.0000,"durationDays":731,"familySize":4,"assignmentType":"Long Term","homeLocation":"Australia","hostLocation":"United States","serviceName":"Service ABC","homeLocationGeoLat":-25.274398,"homeLocationGeoLng":133.775136,"hostLocationGeoLat":37.09024,"hostLocationGeoLng":-95.712891}', '{"client":"ABC Company","totalUSD":7110.0000,"durationDays":731,"familySize":4,"assignmentType":"Long Term","homeLocation":"Australia","hostLocation":"United States","serviceName":"Service XYZ","homeLocationGeoLat":-25.274398,"homeLocationGeoLng":133.775136,"hostLocationGeoLat":37.09024,"hostLocationGeoLng":-95.712891}'))
```

I am trying to parse the JSON into a data.frame using fromJSON from the rjson package.

I cast the column as character type and then attempt to parse:

```
> df$json <- as.character(df$json)
> final <- fromJSON(json_str = df$json)
```

However, it only seems to give me the first row of JSON, whereas I expect 2 rows.

How can I parse the JSON into a data.frame from df$json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want a resultant data frame from this exercise, so:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(df$json, rjson::fromJSON))

##         client totalUSD durationDays familySize assignmentType homeLocation  hostLocation serviceName homeLocationGeoLat
## 2  ABC Company     7110          731          4      Long Term    Australia United States Service ABC           -25.2744
## 21 ABC Company     7110          731          4      Long Term    Australia United States Service XYZ           -25.2744
##    homeLocationGeoLng hostLocationGeoLat hostLocationGeoLng
## 2            133.7751           37.09024          -95.71289
## 21           133.7751           37.09024          -95.71289
```

The *exact* same results will come from:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(df$json, jsonlite::fromJSON))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(df$json, RJSONIO::fromJSON))
```

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rjson’

Comment: Well, _did you install it_?

Comment: Just writing library(rjson) didn't work. install.packages('rjson') now it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you may need to study up on both R and SO etiquette a bit.

Comment: Yes! I am trying hard :))